# Rpy2 package installation error

Tags: python, rpy2

I am trying to install a package for R in Jupyter . 
I have a made a couple of temporary environment variables as well. 
These variables also exist in my system variables.

```
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3'    
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:/Users/username/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2'
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('missForest')
```

The error is given below :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-b46ffcebb3d6> in <module>()
      3 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
      4 utils = importr('utils')
----> 5 utils.install_packages('missForest')

C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
    177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    179 
    180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
    105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    108         return res

RRuntimeError: Error: unable to create temporary directory 'C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\file32b47907709e'
```

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like the space in `Program Files`?  Or maybe it needs administrator permission to make the target directory?

Comment: I have no issues installing packages from R environment . So I am assuming its not an issue with admin permission. Also I tried without spaces in `Program Files` , the error still remains.

Comment: Does the parent directory `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin` exist?  This is not the same location as the `R_HOME` environment variable (is it supposed to be?)

Comment: The parent directory does exist . The location is definitely not the same as `R_HOME` , but I am not sure why this happening myself. I have R Studio and thus I have put another user in system variables for `R_USER` as `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin` . I tried removing it and it still shows me the same error.

Comment: Hmm.  Does `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\file32b47907709e` _already_ exist, either as a directory or a plain file?

Comment: No , it dosent .

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas then.